# How to find Magento Page Source Bug

Tags: html, cms-block

I have applied a theme to my magento site. I find that when the website gets minimized to a certiain size there is a slight code bug where I see a piece of text that needs to be deleted. I need to delete that piece of text in the background. I have inspected the element and the page source. Turns out the text location is only visible in the page source. How do I find where in Magento CMS I can edit that specific Page source text block that I need deleted?

Comment: Enable the path hint and check the content parent div

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure it's coming from a CMS page then you can query the DB directly to find out which page it is. Once you located the page edit it in  the admin section of magento.

To find the page try this:

```
select * from cms_block where content like '%WHATEVER YOU WANT TO SEARCH%';
```

With this you can do a search for cms blocks that contain the text you inserted in the query above, get the id or the title of the block and go to the admin of magento to edit it.